# 301 .htaccess redirect my all pages to a new site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Thanks for taking a look to my question.

### Question:

I want my domain to be redirected to other domain, I did this with the help of .htaccess file but the issue is if I try to open the home page its working good but if I open any links cached by Google which is a inner page , it does not work 
So for example if my domain is xyz.com and it needs to be redirected to abc.com then if google has cached xyz.com/about.html if i click on it going to google it is searching abc.com/about.html which is not preset on abc.com.

Please help.
Thanks

---

Comment: Show the relevant code of your .htaccess file, so people can help you.

Comment: I have used Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/

Comment: Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/